# How to put PyTest test case report into a variable

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest

I'm using a hook fixture to generate custom report when the test case failed:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(rep, 'extra', [])
    if rep.when == 'call' and rep.failed:
```

Is it possible to get console PyTest report with stdout/stderr into a string variable in term of further using? (in this fixture)
E.g. `report = outcome...`

Comment: You can monkeypatch `sys.stdout` early enough with a `io.StringIO` and use that for output collection. Question is why you want the complete output and what exactly you want to customize. E.g. you can easily add custom report sections or header info.

Answer (score 0):

It was done by getting required info directly from `rep` object, where `rep = outcome.get_result()`:

```
def __create_description(self, report):
    stdout = getattr(report, "capstdout")
    longreprtext = getattr(report, "longreprtext")
    delimiter = "\n=============================\n"
    description = delimiter + "Captured stdout:\n" \
                  + stdout + delimiter + "Traceback:\n" + longreprtext
    return description
```